# How to configure Varnish not to cache a particular folder?

Tags: apache-2.2, http, varnish, cache

I would like to set up Varnish as reverse proxy cache for Apache.

How can I setup Varnish so that it does not cache content from a particular folder (and its subfolders), let's say /public_html/shop/

Comment: Can you provide your current VCL config?

Comment: @ShaneMadden As I mentioned in the question, I "would like to" setup Varnish. So there's no current config to speak of. Let's assume Varnish default config. In any case, I suspect basing the answer on default config would be useful to more users than basing it on a particular config.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd want something like this in your `vcl_recv`:

```
if (req.url ~ "^/path/to/exclude/") {
  return (pass);
}
```

You'll probably need to familiarize yourself with the basics of what the default VCL is doing and adjust for your content - for example, by default, it'll avoid caching anything when the client sends any cookies on the assumption that your content might vary based on sent cookies.